# Is there a command to count all files number of a HDFS path?

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

For example

```
hdfs_path="/user/label/"
hadoop fs -ls $hdfs_path

/user/label/2021-07-01
/user/label/2021-07-02
..., ...
/user/label/2021-11-12
/user/label/2021-11-13
```

I want to count all files number in the timestamp sub-directory like `/user/label/2021-07-01`, `/user/label/2021-07-02` and so on.

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -count $hdfs_path/*
```

This command is enough to count the files number of a subdirectory of an HDFS path and sincerely thanks for @Ben Watson